# performance issue with getting clob object as a string with java ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to fetach CLOB object from ORACLE DB with my java application. This CLOB object contains XML data. This is actually a performance implication for me which is consuming around 3 minutes of time to process. If my XML content becomes more, then the processing time is reaching beyond the accepted time intervels.

Is there any other alternative to get the XML content(CLOB object) from DB with no performance issues? 
Using oracle 10g.

Comment: If you can give more details about what you want to do with xml content then that might help

Comment: @loki; i am constructing InputStream object with this XML content and giving to BIRT tool as input for repor generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing xml in form of clob, you can try using oracle xml db.
Check out more details at : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-features/xmldb/overview/index.html.

Using xml DB using directly run queries on xml data, so you dont need to bring whole of data in java layer all the time which will improve performance.

EDIT:

If xml db is not an option for you then you need to make changes to java implementation. Based on your question i can see that the size of clob is causing the delay in fetching data.
You start a background thread which can load your data in a cache [you can create a simple cache based on Map] and then instead of going to DB you can check in cache first. This can reduce time considerably for you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I can't change the process for the insertion of XML as a clob object. This is not in my boundary. so, i should to have a leight weight process to fetch the content. Moreover the one you suggested is comes up with oracle 11g only.

Comment: XMLDB came lot earlier than 11g even 9i has it.